# undefined method `map' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I trying to make drop-down list in form from my database data. I have table with wastes, and boolean is it toxic or not.

I tried to get this with this code:

```
<%= collection_select(:waste, :code, Waste.find_by_istoxic(true), :id, :code) %>
```

but I got error "undefined method `map' for #

With this it's works:

```
<%= collection_select(:waste, :code, Waste.all, :id, :code) %>
```

but I need some filtering.

I tried to make some like this but with no success:

```
<%= collection_select(:waste, :code, @toxicwastes, :id, :code) %>
```

and in controller:

```
@toxicwastes = Waste.find_by_istoxic(true)
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

`find_by_*` returns a single record, you want to use `find_all_by_*` instead.

Comment: @PankajSonawane: Then create a new question with your problem and somebody will answer it.